# iOS 8 Constraints

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode6, nslayoutconstraint

I have an application in Xcode with storyboard. I have a label in center and background image.[image]

I added 4 constraints for both label and background image view. But when I run my app on simulator everything probably works, but text does not scale in label.[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: try disabling auto classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per you your question.

1.) Set label as vertically and horizontally centre.

2.) Then you need to give it leading and trailing space and you also need give aspect ratio to the label.

3.) Then you to set Alignment,Baseline,Auto shrink,mode and line break.

Please View the below images of how the constraints which i've set and how i've changed the size of text. I've also added result images for iPhone 5,6 and 6 Plus.

[image]

[image]

Result:

[image]
[image]

iPhone 6 Plus:
[image]

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the text is too big, to be displayed on your chosen device (iPhone 6). What you need to do, is select the label (in storyboard), go to `Attibutes Inspector`, then set the `Autoshrink` to `Minimum font size`, then input your minimum font size.